# How can I get the last occurrence of a repeated string in the text file?

Tags: command-line, scripts, text-processing, text, sort

I have a data file consists of several rows and columns with numeric and string data. Some string and numeric patterns are repeated. I need to extract last repeated pattern. For example;

```
715 ANKR PRN 1 value 1
760 ISTA PRN 2 value 2
715 ANKR PRN 1 value 3
760 ISTA PRN 2 value 4
715 ANKR PRN 1 value 5
760 ISTA PRN 2 value 6
  1 ANKR PRN 7 value 8
  2 ISTA PRN 7 value 9
  1 ANKR PRN 7 value 10
  3 ISTA PRN 7 value 11
  1 ANKR PRN 7 value 12
```

in this example "715 ANKR PRN 1", "760 ISTA PRN 2" and "1 ANKR PRN 7"are repeated 3 times within the data file. I need to extract last repeated patterns and sort as follows;

```
715 ANKR PRN 1 value 5
760 ISTA PRN 2 value 6
  1 ANKR PRN 7 value 12
```

Comment: Where are "715 ANKR PRN 1", "760 ISTA PRN 2" and "1 ANKR PRN 7" stored? In a file?

Comment: yes they are stored in the text file

Comment: Let me rephrase that: there is also another "unique" pattern ("3 ISTA PRN 7"), so I don't understand if you want to extract each last "unique" pattern (and you missed "3 ISTA PRN 7") or if you have a defined subset of patterns to extract stored somehwere else (e.g. in other file).

Comment: each last repeated pattern I want to extract not a unique one. Unique one can be ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using standard tools, `sort`, `rev`, `uniq`:

```
% sort -k1,5 -k6,6nr file.txt | rev | uniq -f1 -d | rev

  1 ANKR PRN 7 value 12
715 ANKR PRN 1 value 5
760 ISTA PRN 2 value 6
```

If you want sort the output as desired:

```
% sort -k1,5 -k6,6nr file.txt | rev | uniq -f1 -d | rev | sort -k6,6n

715 ANKR PRN 1 value 5
760 ISTA PRN 2 value 6
  1 ANKR PRN 7 value 12
```

Comment: Simple, good looking and extremely fast +1

Comment: @heemayl if I also want to extract unique line (no repeated pattern; 3 ISTA PRN 7 value 11) how could you modify your code?

Comment: @deepblue_86 I would do `sort -k1,5 -k6,6nr file.txt | rev | uniq -f1 -u | rev`

Comment: @heemayl this produce the first repeated line not the last one

Comment: @deepblue_86 check again..it is working perfectly for your given example..you can even make it a bit shorter `sort -k1,5 file.txt | rev | uniq -f1 -u | rev`

Comment: @heemayl, I don't know how I couldn't work correctly but here is the result after your code ; 2 ISTA PRN 7 value 9;
  3 ISTA PRN 7 value 11

Comment: @deepblue_86 This is correct, according to the definition of yours these are unique lines..check the input again..

Comment: it is oked @heemayl, my mistake

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
awk '{a[$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5] = $6; c[$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5]++}; END{for (i in a) {if (c[i]>1) print i,a[i]}}'
```

Testing with your input

```
$ awk '{a[$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5] = $6; c[$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5]++}; END{for (i in a) {if (c[i]>1) print i,a[i]}}' file
715 ANKR PRN 1 value 5
760 ISTA PRN 2 value 6
1 ANKR PRN 7 value 12
```